# XML result from web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to get a XML result from the webservice. I have tried the below code

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    string xml = "http://www.examplexml.com/2323223";

    doc.Load(xml);
    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/-soapenv:Envelope/-soapenv:Body/
                                                -GetPasswordResponse/Password", nsmgr);
    string password = node.InnerText;
```

But I couldn't get the result, It shows the error Namespace prefix 'soapenv' is not defined. Any help would be helpful for me.

Comment: You only registered `xsl` prefix to `nsmgr`, that's why `soapenv` considered 'not defined'... also I don't think you need those `-` in that particular xpath

Comment: shall i also have to register soapenv?

Comment: Yup. All prefix you'll be using in your xpath

Comment: is registering made with this url w3.org/1999/soapenv/Transform??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solve your problem to register infopath of prefixes. For example as you did for "xsl".

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "Here is the URL of mention at starting point in your xml file");
```

So it should be look like this,

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
```

Comment: No. This is for **xsl** prefix. For "soapenv", it should be mentioned in xml file. Please check at starting of your xml file. It should be there.

Comment: yeah , this is the result comes from the browser <soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><GetPasswordResponse><Password>xxxx</Password></GetPasswordResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>  and i have to retrive the password inner text

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try that namespace.

Comment: its working fine but im getting null value from the inner text

Comment: Did you tried both namespaces?? Please try both and let me which is working.

Comment: wow great working fine ,  i got it through this register http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/   thanks for you , give your mail  lol :P